# c++ destructor seg fault when using linked list

Tags: c++, destructor

I currently have a seg fault when coding with c++, the Valgrind and gdb has told me that my destructor is having some problem

```
//implementing constructor and destructor
list::list(){
        node * head = NULL;
}
list::~list(){
        if(head != NULL){
        delete head;}
}

//some code in a function that deal with linked list

head = new node;
setnull(head);
node * temp;
temp = head;

//....
//after some insert

temp->next = new node;
temp = temp->next;
setnull(temp);//setting elements in the list to null and set node->next to null
```

In the main

```
  list My_list;
        node * head=NULL;
        int i = 0;
        char next_move[20];

        My_list.build(head,i);
```

information from Valgrind

```
==9921== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9921==    at 0x108E14: list::~list() (list.cpp:7)
==9921==    by 0x10988D: main (main.cpp:4)
==9921== 
==9921== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9921==    at 0x4C311F1: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9921==    by 0x108E29: list::~list() (list.cpp:8)
==9921==    by 0x10988D: main (main.cpp:4)
==9921== 
==9921== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==9921==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9921==    by 0x108E29: list::~list() (list.cpp:8)
==9921==    by 0x10988D: main (main.cpp:4)
==9921==  Address 0x3 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9921==
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Looks like you initialize a variable `head` local to the constructor of `list`. In the destructor, you refer to a data meber instead. That might be the reason for the valgrind complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly this

```
list::list(){
    node * head = NULL;
}
```

should be this

```
list::list() {
    head = NULL;
}
```

In your code you've declared a variable called `head` in your constructor, that's a different variable from the `head` in your `list` class. So the `head` variable in the `list` class is uninitialised and that explains the valgrind error you see (i.e. `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`). You want the constructor to initialise variables in the list class.

I wouldn't be surprised if there are more errors as well, so fixing that error may not fix your program. But try that fix and see how you go.

Comment: Even better would be actually *initializing* the member `list::list() : head(nullptr) { }`